# How can i insert part of an External file in mysql via PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having a bit of trouble getting help for this:

how can i read text from an external XML file, search through it for specific terms and save whatever's between those tags in my MySQL db with php?

I'm coding a website on which I want to include an address search, but I need it to be converted to lat and lon. i know its possible, but i don't know where to begin, since I am not very good in PHP.

heres what i want to achieve in some sort of pseudocode:

```
take userinput
open url maps.google.../userinput
find <location><lat>(Latitude)</lat>
save (Latitude) to mysql as 'lat'
find <lon>(Longitude)</lon></location>
save (Longitude) to mysql as 'lon'
```

can someebody help me with this? i would be very grateful

thanks in advance

Comment: With an XML parser obviously.

Comment: obviously it's not obvious or he wouldn't be asking..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
require_once('PHPExcel/IOFactory.php');
require_once('PHPExcel.php');

$sheet_path ="test.xlsx"
$obj_excel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($sheet_path);

$get_sheets='';
$get_sheetData = "";

$sheet = $obj_excel->getSheetByName('Sheet1');
$get_sheetData=$sheet->toArray(null,true,true,true);
// You will get whole sheet data into array format in $get_sheetData variable
```

Make a curl call to this URL .

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=$address&key=API_KEY  // Please assign address value from sheet to $address variable

You will get latitude and longitude in json then decode that json and store it into database.

Comment: thank you, i got it! i created a function which inserts the geolocation into forms and saves it with the rest in the DB

Answer (score 0):

This is a two part question, so you get a two part answer.

**Extracting from XML**

1) You can convert your XML to a native array with this little trick

```
$array = json_decode(json_encode(simplexml_load_string($xmlstring)),TRUE);
```

2) Now you can access the parts of your XML from the `$array` array. [Here's an example.](https://3v4l.org/v9ign)

**Geocoding Addresses**

Geocoding is the process of converting an address to coordinates. Google has a really easy API that will do this for you (for free!). [Check it out here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro) and try to work though it. If you have trouble with it please feel free to post a new question with the code you've tried. Try it yourself first and if you need help, that's what we're here for.